# What's the right way to do long-running processes on app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, goroutine

I'm working with Go on App Engine and I'm trying to build an API that needs to perform a long-running background task - in this case it needs to parse and chunk a big file out to task queues. I'd like it to return a 200 and close the user connection immediately and let the process keep running in the background until it's complete (this could take 5-10 minutes). Task queues alone don't really work for my use case because parsing the initial file can take more than the time limit for an API request.

At first I tried a Go routine as a solution for this problem. This failed because my app engine context expired as soon as the parent function closed the user connection. (I suppose I could try writing a go routine that doesn't require a context, but then I'd lose logging and I'd need to fetch the entire remote file and pass it to the go routine.)

Looking through the docs, it looks like App Engine used to have functionality to support exactly what I want to do: [runtime.RunInBackground], but that functionality is now deprecated and the replacement isn't obvious.

Is there a "right" or recommended way to do background processing now?

I suppose I could put a link to my big file into a task queue, but if I understand correctly, even functions called through task queues have to complete execution within a specified amount of time (is it 90 seconds?) I need to be able to run longer than that.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you can't use a taskqueue, then probably your only option is the flex environment.

Comment: Actually, what you can probably do is use resumeable uploads with gcloud, then have it hit another endpoint with a task queue when it is finished uploading. If worst comes to worst, you could use flex for just the one endpoint that doesn't work in regular, then handle the rest in the standard environment.

Comment: When you say _"context"_, I take it you mean a `context.Context` parameter. If so: you probably passed the request context in to the routine, there's no reason you couldn't pass in a `context.Background()` value instead. Because otherwise, the request context would've gotten cancelled and halted your routine. If you pass in your own context, it can run for as long as you like.

Comment: Elias - I tried that, but I need to grab a external data which means I need to use urlfetch. When I pass urlfetch a context from context.Background() it panics with a "not an app engine context" error.

Comment: PS. I tried passing the file to the go routine so I wouldn't need urlfetch. But I have the same panic problem using a context.Background() for the taskqueue. Not sure why they chose to panic rather than just return an error.

Answer (score 0):

try using:
appengine.BackgroundContext()
it should be long-lived but will only work on GAE Flex